# Classification of degree one map between two closed orientable surfaces without using induction on the genus

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

A theorem of Edmonds (see Theorem 3.1. of ["Deformation of Maps to Branched Coverings in Dimension Two"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971246?seq=1)) says that

**Theorem 1**: *A degree-one map between closed orientable surfaces is homotopic to a pinch map (quotient map obtained from identifying a connected compact bordered sub-surface with one boundary component to a point).*

By Theorem 1, we have Theorem 2 below.

**Theorem 2**: *A degree-one map between closed orientable surfaces, when it induces an injective map between the fundamental groups, is homotopic to a homeomorphism.*

Edmonds' proof of Theorem 1 is based on the induction of the genus. Also, there is a proof of Theorem 2 **without** using induction; for example, see the first proof of Theorem 8.9. of  "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups."

> **Question:** Is there any proof of Theorem 1 **without** using induction on the genus?

I am looking for a reference that has a proof of Theorem 1 in the flavor of the proof of Theorem 8.9. like as given in  "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups. *My Question can be a little vague or weird. Sorry for this.*

Comment: I thought up and wrote down a simpler proof of the Edmonds theorem which goes in one step (without induction) and which is more natural (in my opinion), it is slightly similar to the Farb-Margalit's proof of the Dehn-Nielsen theorem https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07813 I will be grateful for any remarks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first proof of 8.9 in the Primer uses the genus (to prove that all pants decompositions of $S$ have the same number of curves).  Proving that the genus of a surface is well-defined is, at some point, an induction.

It is possible (in my mind at least) that the second proof of Theorem 8.9, based on harmonic maps, gives a proof which more carefully hides the use of induction.  (I mean, at some point there will be a proof that diffeomorphisms preserve dimension, which will rely on the pigeonhole principle, which is more-or-less an induction.)

---

There is an area of foundations called [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics).  I have not heard of an analysis of low-dimensional topology (or more specifically the mapping class group) from this viewpoint.  Perhaps a first step would be to formalise some of the most important tools (the Alexander trick, the Dehn-Nielsen-Baer theorem) in [Lean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_(proof_assistant)) (for example).

I imagine that this would be a huge undertaking. But I am very old, and have none of the courage of youth.